# Subdomain 403 forbidden after RewriteEngine On

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently added the following commands to my htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /stop-saying-i-have-a-boyfriend http://lunalunamag.com/2013/09/05/stop-boyfriend/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

And since then my subdomains show 403 forbidden. (ex: http://crystal.eberhardtsmith.com)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you rename this .htaccess does 403 go away?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The file is called .htaccess

Comment: 1. Rename .htaccess to .htaccess.bak 2. Visit subdomain again 3. See 403 is still there?

Comment: 403 is gone but the RewriteEngine On isn't working now.

Comment: What changed you made to fix 403?

Comment: I renamed the .htaccess to .htaccess.bak like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^stop-saying-i-have-a-boyfriend http://lunalunamag.com/2013/09/05/stop-boyfriend/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```